# retrieve a result when the partition is not known (but row key is)

Tags: .net-core, azure-table-storage

In my case (I happen to have only two types for each entry, so 2 partitions, and the row key is unique) I can write an iterative set of queries going over all possible partitions like this:

```cs
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<JobStatus>(Mode.GreyScale.Description(), id);

TableResult query = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
if (query.Result != null)
{
    return new OkObjectResult((JobStatus)query.Result);
}
else
{
    retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<JobStatus>(Mode.Sepia.Description(), id);

    query = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
    if (query.Result != null)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult((JobStatus)query.Result);

    }
}
return new NotFoundResult();
```

The thing is, that is clearly inefficient (imagine if there were hundreds of types!). Does azure storage tables provide an efficient means to query when you know only the row key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does azure storage tables provide an efficient means to query when you
>   know only the row key?

Simple answer to your question is no, there's no efficient way to query table when you only know the RowKey. Table Service will do full table scan going from one partition to another and find entities with matching RowKey.

In your case, you would probably want to use [`TableQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablequery?view=azure-dotnet) to create your query and then either call [`ExecuteQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executequery?view=azure-dotnet) or [`ExecuteQuerySegmented`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmented?view=azure-dotnet) to get query results.

```
        TableQuery query = new TableQuery().Where("RowKey eq 'Your Row Key'");
        var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

Comment: that still sounds hopeful to me .. I don't see an overload of Retrieve that accepts only a row key -- however your answer kinda indicates that there is something like that.

Comment: Retrieve operation is used for retrieving only a single entity. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. I know I want only a single answer (my row keys _are_ unique) -- is it possible to do something like this on Retrieve?

Comment: You mentioned that you only have two partition keys in your table. In that case you can possibly use retrieve operation. Try it with first partition key and row key combination. If the result is null, then try with second partition key and row key combination.

Comment: that's what is in the OP .. sigh, I was really just looking for a partition-invariant way to skip compiling a list of 0-1 entities, then converting to a single entity or null .. when I know in advance that the list will never be plural